# Bug detection terminal in Swift cites variable as issue - variable doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

The first view controller of my project crashed when segue'd to from another view controller - but not when it loads. I get this error message:

```
2016-01-05 20:06:33.836 collaboration[48812:1788623] -[collaboration.createAccountViewController loginExisting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796cc950
2016-01-05 20:06:33.849 collaboration[48812:1788623] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[collaboration.createAccountViewController loginExisting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796cc950'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00396a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022c5e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0039fd63 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x002dd6bd ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x002dd28e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022da0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    6   UIKit                               0x00df7b79 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
    7   UIKit                               0x00df7af8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    8   UIKit                               0x00f978f8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
    9   UIKit                               0x00f97c78 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 408
    10  UIKit                               0x00f96c7e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
    11  UIKit                               0x00e74182 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1095
    12  UIKit                               0x00e75220 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
    13  UIKit                               0x00e19f93 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
    14  UIKit                               0x00def668 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7802
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x002b06ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x002a638b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x002a57a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x002a50e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x002a4efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x07075664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x070754a1 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x00df5bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    23  collaboration                       0x00085a3c main + 140
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x039bca21 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

As you can see, it cites the variable 'loginExisting' as the issue, however loginExisting is not a variable on in any of my scripts (it was before but has since been removes). How can I 'refresh' XCode so that it forgets about the absent variable? I have tried restarting my machine and cleaning XCode but have had not success.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, the error is telling you that the `loginExisting:` method doesn't exist on your `createAccountViewController` class. This has nothing to do with any variable.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your storyboard that's crashing and right click the yellow icon at the top of the ViewController.

[image: Icon]

After right clicking, look towards the bottom where it says "Received actions" and delete all of the actions pertaining to the `loginExisting` method.

This is one of many possible culprits, but this tends to be the most common.

EDIT: It's also possible that you have a property (`IBOutlet`) connected to the storyboard that no longer exists which will throw an error.